# different table rows per data in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay, so I'm having hard time understanding how ng-repeat builds tables. What I'm trying to do is that per row, there is customer name and address. I can't get it to work. Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="myController">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Company Name</th>
       <th>Address</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="company in fieldData" row-id="{{ company.name }}">
       <td>{{ company.name }}</td><td>{{ company.address }}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

and here is my script:

```
    var companyName = [];
    var companyAddress = [];

    $scope.fieldData = [];

    $(data).find('record').each(function () {
      companyName.push($(this).record(6));
      companyAddress.push($(this).record(47));
    });

    $scope.fieldData.push({
      name: companyName,
      address: companyAddress
    })
```

So, in companyName and companyAddress arrays, there are name and addresses being stored. But I can't get one company & address per row. Any ideas?

Comment: Currently you have a single object in your fieldData array since you call push only once and insert a single object with arrays as it properties. I suggest to go other the array that you've created and call push for every item. You can also avoid using jquery and then simply create the fieldData array on the fly

Comment: That's cause your data isn't quite structured right. Your angular properties are binding to arrays.

Comment: could you help me with an example?

Comment: no wait I got it. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You built an one element array with one object of two arrays, like:

```
fieldData: [
    {
        name: [
            'name1', 'name2', 'etc'
        ],
        address: [
            'addr1', 'addr2', 'etc'
        ]
    }
]
```

You want to have an array of objects with name and address fields:

```
fieldData: [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        address: 'addr1'
    },
    {
        name: 'name2',
        address: 'addr2'
    },
    {
        name: 'etc',
        address: 'etc'
    }
]
```

To achieve that, go with:

```
$scope.fieldData = [];

$(data).find('record').each(function (item) {
  $scope.fieldData.push({
    name: item.record(6),
    address: item.record(47)
  });
});
```